# Adding resource filter for every eclipse project created and imported

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to write a plugin that just adds resource filter to the .project file that is created/imported. I know the following way to add a resource filter.

```
IProject.createFilter(IResourceFilterDescription.EXCLUDE_ALL | IResourceFilterDescription.FOLDERS | IResourceFilterDescription.INHERITABLE, new FileInfoMatcherDescription("org.eclipse.ui.ide.multiFilter", theFilter),  IResource.BACKGROUND_REFRESH, monitor);
```

I'm wondering what is the right extension point where I can hook this code. I couldn't find a generic place which would work to all kinds of projects (not just java projects).

My intention is to filter out lots of unwanted files coming from a proprietary source control system.

Comment: So there's no existing plug-in to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IResourceChangeListener. You can find more info [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_events.htm).

If you are using JDT, you can also use

```
JavaCore.addElementChangedListener(listener);
```

the listener must implement `org.eclipse.jdt.core.IElementChangedListener`.